# Java XML Unmarshalling fails on ampersand (&amp;) using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<details>
  ...
  <address1>Test&amp;Address</address1>
  ...
</details>
```

When I try to unmarshal it using JAXB, it throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "Address" must end with the ';' delimiter.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:194)
```

But when I changed the `&amp;` in the XML to `&apos;`, it works. Looks like the problem is only with ampersand `&amp;` and I cannot understand why.

The code to unmarshal is:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("some.package.name", this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
```

Anyone have some insight?

EDIT: I tried the solution suggested by @abhin4v below (ie, add a space after `&amp;`), but it doesn't seem to work too. Here's the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:194)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, you could certainly report it. As an option, you can just stick with <![CDATA[...]]> and not care about special symbols.

Comment: JRE 1.6.0_20 doesn't have this problem. Probably, it's already fixed.

Comment: @axtavt: Can you point me to any documents (release notes, maybe?) that confirms this?

Comment: I just wrote a quick unit test under JDK 1.6.0_16, works there also. Which version of JDK and/or JAXB are you using?

Comment: I would try using the sun internal xml parser instead of whatever xerces implementation you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is because of the framework I'm using ([Mentawai framework](http://www.mentaframework.org/)). The said XML comes from the POST body of an HTTP request.

Apparently, the framework converts the character entities in the XML body, therefore, `&amp;` becomes `&` and the unmarshaller fails to unmarshal the XML.

Comment: Urgh, that's a pretty dumb thing for it to do. Doesn't exactly inspire confidence in the rest of the framework.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's the choice of the company to use this particular framework. I can only complain :(

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with the framework being used. Mentawai does not perform any kind o conversion on the HTTP level. It passes the POST parameters as is.

Answer (score 3):

Xerces converts `&amp;` to `&` and then tries to resolve `&Address` which fails because it does not end with `;`. <strike>Put a space between `&` and `Address` and it should work.</strike> Putting a space will not work as Xerces will now try to resolve `&` and throw the second error given in OP. You can wrap the test in a CDATA section and Xerces will not try to resolve the entities.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this too. First pass I simply replaced the &amp to a token string (AMPERSAND_TOKEN), sent it through JAXB, then re-replaced the ampersand. Not ideal, but it was a quick fix.

Second pass I made a lot of significant changes, so I'm not sure what exactly solved the problem. I suspect that providing JAXB access to the html dtds made it much happier, but that's only a guess and could be specific to my project.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I've found that adding **amp;** will fix the unmarshalling error. You want it to look like this:

```
<address1>Test&amp;amp;Address</address1>
```

I think this tells the unmarshaller that the ampersand should be read as a data value (text in this case) instead of an entity identifier. You can see by your errors that it's attempting to view "Address", which immediately follows the `&amp;`, as an entity name